# Can't get Nutch to add new documents below a certain level

Tags: nutch

I have a web site serving a series of documents (pdf's) and am using Nutch 1.8 to index them in solr.  The base url is

```
http://localhost/
```

and the documents are stored in a series of directories in the directory

```
http://localhost/doccontrol/
```

, e.g.

/
|_doccontrol
    |_DC-10 Incoming Correspondence
    |_DC-11 Outgoing Correspondence

If when I first run nutch the folders DC-10 and DC-11 contain all the files to be indexed then nutch crawls everything without a problem - GOOD :-)

If I add a new folder or documents to the root or doccontrol folders then the next time nutch runs it crawls all the new files and indexes them - GOOD :-)

However any new files that are added to the DC-10 or DC-11 directories are not indexed with nutch's output as follows (summarised):

```
Injector: starting at 2014-08-29 15:19:59
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: overwrite: true
Injector: update: false
Injector: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:02, elapsed: 00:00:02
Fri Aug 29 15:20:02 EST 2014 : Iteration 1 of 4
Generating a new segment
Generator: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:02
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: false
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 50000
Generator: Partitioning selected urls for politeness.
Generator: segment: crawl/segments/20140829152005
Generator: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:06, elapsed: 00:00:03
Operating on segment : 20140829152005
Fetching : 20140829152005
Fetcher: Your 'http.agent.name' value should be listed first in 'http.robots.agents' property.
Fetcher: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:06
Fetcher: segment: crawl/segments/20140829152005
Fetcher Timelimit set for : 1409354406733
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 50
Fetcher: time-out divisor: 2
QueueFeeder finished: total 1 records + hit by time limit :0
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
fetching http://ws0895/doccontrol/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
.
.
.
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0
-activeThreads=0
Fetcher: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:09, elapsed: 00:00:02
Parsing : 20140829152005
ParseSegment: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:09
ParseSegment: segment: crawl/segments/20140829152005
Parsed (3ms):http://ws0895/doccontrol/
ParseSegment: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:10, elapsed: 00:00:01
CrawlDB update
CrawlDb update: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:11
CrawlDb update: db: crawl/crawldb
CrawlDb update: segments: [crawl/segments/20140829152005]
CrawlDb update: additions allowed: true
CrawlDb update: URL normalizing: false
CrawlDb update: URL filtering: false
CrawlDb update: 404 purging: false
CrawlDb update: Merging segment data into db.
CrawlDb update: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:12, elapsed: 00:00:01
Link inversion
LinkDb: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:13
LinkDb: linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: URL normalize: true
LinkDb: URL filter: true
LinkDb: internal links will be ignored.
LinkDb: adding segment: crawl/segments/20140829152005
LinkDb: merging with existing linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:15, elapsed: 00:00:02
Dedup on crawldb
Indexing 20140829152005 on SOLR index -> http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1
Indexer: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:19
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexer: finished at 2014-08-29 15:20:20, elapsed: 00:00:01
Cleanup on SOLR index -> http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1
Fri Aug 29 15:20:22 EST 2014 : Iteration 2 of 4
Generating a new segment
Generator: starting at 2014-08-29 15:20:23
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: false
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 50000
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
```

BAD - :-(

What I'd like nutch to do is to index any newly added docs whatever level they were added at.

My nutch command is as follows:

```
bin/crawl urls crawl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1 4
```

My nutch-site.xml contains:

```
<property>
  <name>db.update.additions.allowed</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>If true, updatedb will add newly discovered URLs, if false
  only already existing URLs in the CrawlDb will be updated and no new
  URLs will be added.
  </description>
 </property>
 <name>db.max.outlinks.per.page</name>
  <value>-1</value>
  <description>The maximum number of outlinks that we'll process for a page.
  If this value is nonnegative (>=0), at most db.max.outlinks.per.page outlinks
  will be processed for a page; otherwise, all outlinks will be processed.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>db.injector.overwrite</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Whether existing records in the CrawlDB will be overwritten
  by injected records.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>db.fetch.schedule.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.nutch.crawl.AdaptiveFetchSchedule</value>
  <description>The implementation of fetch schedule. DefaultFetchSchedule simply
  adds the original fetchInterval to the last fetch time, regardless of
  page changes.</description>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>db.fetch.schedule.adaptive.min_interval</name>
  <value>86400.0</value>
  <description>Minimum fetchInterval, in seconds.</description>
 </property>
  <property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
  <value>1209600</value>
  <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (14 days).
  </description>
 </property>
```

Is what I am trying to do (recrawl any newly added documents at any level) impossible?

Or (more likely) am I missing something in the config?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The documents you are missing are not indexed probably because the 
`db.fetch.interval.default`
parameter in nutch-site.xml value is 30 days. Nutch is not going to see if there is anything new in /DC-10 for a while. If you set that to be

> ```
> <property>
>    <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
>    <value>86400</value>
>    <description>Number of seconds between re-fetches of a page. (86400 = 1 day)
>    </description>
> </property>
> ```

Then you will recrawl every day. Also, I think the nutch users mailing list is more active than stackoverflow for Nutch related stuff.